# Insert new row into DataGrid, with different columns C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to insert a new row in `DaraGridView` (C#), witch has only 3 rows from the 6 from `DataBindingSource` (it is one dataset with one `DataTable`).

This is the code I was trying to write, but it gets me an exception.
The exception is that is unable to cast `obj` of type dataset to binding source, from this function, at the method: `public void Invoke(params object[] args)` from weak delegate list.

```
private void cmdNewRow_CustomExecute(object sender,
    ExecutionEventArgs<ICommandButtonExecutor> e)
{
    Fev018DataSet ds = (Fev018DataSet)(((BindingSource)
        FahrzeugBarcodeBindingSource.DataSource).DataSource);
    int a = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    customGridViewBarcodes.AddNewRow();
    bool locked = false;
    try
    {
        while (!locked)
        {
            locked = Monitor.TryEnter(this, 100);
            if (!locked)
                Application.DoEvents(); // do events to prevent 
            // prevent freezing von Invokes
        }
        if ((methodInfo == null) || (target == null)) return;
        try
        {
            if (target.IsAlive)
                methodInfo.Invoke(target.Target, args);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
        {
            // Get the _remoteStackTraceString of the Exception class
            FieldInfo remoteStackTraceString = typeof(Exception)
                .GetField("_remoteStackTraceString",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); // MS.Net
            if (remoteStackTraceString == null)
                remoteStackTraceString = typeof(Exception)
                .GetField("remote_stack_trace",
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic); // Mono
            // Set the InnerException._remoteStackTraceString
            // to the current InnerException.StackTrace
            remoteStackTraceString.SetValue(ex.InnerException,
                ex.InnerException.StackTrace + Environment.NewLine);
            // Throw the new exception
            throw ex.InnerException;
        }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (locked)
            Monitor.Exit(this);
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: On which line exactly?

Comment: Yep, where do you exactly get the Exception?

Comment: At the method public void Invoke(params object[] args) from weak delegate list. cs:

Comment: But we don't see Invoke method anywhere in the posted code, Please put the full code.

Comment: @StefanaB: Your code doesn't help a bit to understand the scenario. Can you please check what type of binding source are you getting in your code. The exception says unable to cast to dataset, so there's a problem while you cast.

Comment: I edited the question with the function witch throws the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the exception is that is unable to cast obj of type dataset to binding source, from this function

When you get this exception at this line

```
Fev018DataSet ds = (Fev018DataSet)(((BindingSource)FahrzeugBarcodeBindingSource.DataSource).DataSource);
```

it simply means the object behind `FahrzeugBarcodeBindingSource.DataSource` is not of type `BindingSource`, but of type `DataSet`.

This line should be

```
Fev018DataSet ds = (Fev018DataSet)FahrzeugBarcodeBindingSource.DataSource;
```

or

```
DataSet ds = (DataSet)FahrzeugBarcodeBindingSource.DataSource;
```

or you assigned a `DataSet` to `FahrzeugBarcodeBindingSource.DataSource` instead of a `BindingSource` by mistake elsewhere in your code.